# Conditional issue(if, else)

Tags: php, wordpress

Hit a bit of a hiccup. I have created a 4 text boxes in a wordpress dashboard, Each corresponding to an if/else condition on a page template.

On the dashboard control end,

```
    array(  "name" => "Antique",
        "desc" => "Enter content for Antique Rugs here.",
        "id" => $shortname."_antique",
        "std" => "",
        "type" => "textarea"),
array(  "name" => "Contemporary",
        "desc" => "Enter content for Contemporary Rugs here.",
        "id" => $shortname."_contemporary",
        "std" => "",
        "type" => "textarea"),
array(  "name" => "Vintage",
        "desc" => "Enter content for Vintage Rugs here.",
        "id" => $shortname."_vintage",
        "std" => "",
        "type" => "textarea"),      
array(  "name" => "Custom",         
        "desc" => "Enter content for Custom Rugs here.",
        "id" => $shortname."_custom",
        "std" => "",
        "type" => "textarea"),
```

(there are more items after the last one so that's what that hanging comma is there for). On the actual template where this content will out put,

```
    if (is_page('Antique'))
{
    if (get_theme_option('antique') != '')
            {echo 'antique';}
}
else if (is_page('Contemporary'))
{
    if (get_theme_option('contemporary') != '')
            {echo 'contemporary';}
}
else if (is_page('Vintage'))
{
        if (get_theme_option('vintage') != '')
            {echo 'vintage';}   
}
    else if (is_page('Custom'))
{
        if (get_theme_option('custom') != '')
            {echo 'custom';}    
}
else
{echo "no content";}
```

The is_page value is the title of the page in question. THe get theme option is the option/content

Now, three of these conditions work flawlessly; contemporary, vintage, and sale all display the content as intended. However, When I try to view the antique content, it goes to the else fall back and just says no content. I'be been staring at this for a while so it's probably just a stupid typo I'm overlooking but can anyone see something wrong with this

Comment: You did try shuffling the if statement (i.e. move the 'Antique' block to an else if, etc.), right? i think the issue may be elsewhere..

Comment: Yes I did try that earlier. I found out that the site isn't reading the antique part specifically. I delete and retyped out the whole array option part for antique thinking it was a typo I didn't see but everything is typed out properly from what I can see now. It still wont output for just this condition:  if (is_page('Antique'))

Comment: Mhm, so the error isn't in this code, afaict, look at the page titles, etc., any way in which this is different from the others.

Comment: Wow okay. I just fixed it... and it was the dumbest mistake too. The page had been titled "Antique " With an additional blank space at the end which screwed up the condition since it was searching for the page "Antique"

I have been going through this thing over and over for the past hour and it was that stupid oversight the whole time

Thanks for taking the time to look through it though

Comment: ^-^ glad you figured it out..